# Polymorphic vector C++ – no matching member function for call to 'compare'

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have an abstract class Type and two inherited classes Type_A, Type_B. I have implemented some sort of comparisons using virtual functions. I would like to make a polymorphic vectors of pointers containing pointers to both Type_A and Type_B. Then I would like to pick two objects from those vectors and compare them, but I am getting the following error:

```
class Type {
public:
 virtual bool compare(const Type_A &other) = 0;
 virtual bool compare(const Type_B &other) = 0;
};

class Type_A : public Type {
string data;
public:
Type_A(string given_data) {
    data = given_data;
}
bool compare(const Type_A& other)  {
    return (data > other.data);
}
bool compare(const Type_B& other) {
      return false;
}
};

class Type_B : public Type {
public:
int data;
Type_B(string given_data) {
    data = stoi(given_data);
}
bool compare(const Type_B& other)  {
    return (data > other.data);
}
bool compare(const Type_A& other) {
    return false;
}
};

int main() {
  vector<Type*> vec1;
  vector<Type*> vec2;
  Type_A test1("ab");
  Type_B test2("ba");
  vec1.push_back(&test1);
  vec2.push_back(&test2);
  cout << vec1[0]->compare(vec2[0]) << endl; //ERROR: no matching member function for call to 'compare'


}
```

Comment: You have declared your `compare()` functions to take references but you are passing references to them. You should either declare the `compare()` functions to use pointers or dereference the pointer before passing them.

Comment: ... and if you look at your compiler's ***full*** error message (I'm confident that it was much, much more than just "no matching member function for call")  it will tell you that you are passing a ***pointer*** type in the function call, but all available overloads take a ***reference*** as a parameter, which gives a big honking clue as to what the problem was. It is true that C++ compiler error messages are quite intimidating. Yet, making a bone-fide effort to delve into error message and attempting to understand what it says will, sometimes, elicit a clue as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

There's two problems. One is that `vec2[0]` is a pointer type but compare expects regular objects. Other is that `Type.compare` expects either `Type_A` or `Type_B` object, not `Type` object. Do:

`vec1[0]->compare(*(Type_B *) vec2[0])`

Comment: For the second problem - double displatch is better solution (aka visitor pattern)